# Is 级 necessary in 优先级

Tags: meaning, synonyms, style

From the dictionary I gather that 优先 by itself means "priority" and so 优先级 means "level of priority".

In a phrase such as 高优先级，or 最高优先级，is the 级 necessary to sound correct, or is it an optional "stylistic" element, as in English where "highest priority" is the same as "highest level of priority"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike English, `（简）优先／（繁）優先` is an adjective while `（简）优先级／（繁）優先級` is a noun.

```
1. （简）这个项目优先级最高。
   （繁）這個項目優先級最高。
```

If you want to use an adjective then the expression will be like

```
2. （简）这个项目是最高优先的。（所以……）
   （繁）這個項目是最高優先的。（所以……）
```

You may notice a small difference in meaning, the first one is often used as response or a single sentence. The second is **NOT** very usually used as only a single sentence, but you can still use it as a single when the `所以` is obvious.

Comment: I don't think 优先 is an adjective but a verb. E.g. 女士优先 cannot be rewritten as 女士是优先; Your example #2 also complies to the rule 'verb + 的 = adjective'.

Comment: @NS.X. In my opinion, `女士优先` is an idiom where 优先 is still an adjective, but it can also be understood as a verb. 也许是形容词直接当作动词来用了吧，和古汉语常见的词类活用一个道理。

Comment: Both are possible actually. There is no need to limit a compound to just one part of speech.

Comment: @NS.X. The example#2 is not 'verb+的'. I noticed that "sth 是 adj" sounds weird, "sth 是 adj 的" sounds better. So I think 是 can be only used between two nouns, "adj+的=noun" is the rule. Maybe this is also a regional problem.

Comment: @MikeManilone I think you're right, it's blurry in Chinese. 动词作定/状语 and 形容词动用 are both very common, too common to make a clear distinction in many cases.

Comment: I rarely see or hear things as in your example #2.

Comment: @fefe yes, that's true, though it's still right and I will not get surprised when I hear it.

Comment: @MikeManilone Well, I will get surprised if hear a native say so.

Comment: @fefe Maybe yet another regional problem :-/